# Questões (id) aleatórias em um registro

Tags: php

Olá,
Eu gostaria de uma ajuda. E se tiverem alguma ideia melhor, será super bem vinda ;)
Basicamente a ideia é fazer uma busca em um banco de questões, escolher aleatoriamente 5 delas e atrelá-las no registro de um candidato que irá fazer essa prova.

```
<?php 
require_once("conecta.php");

$nome = "Maria";
$query = "SELECT * FROM questoes ORDER BY RAND() limit 5";

$sql = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
while ($perguntas = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo $perguntas['id'];    
}

$query2 = "INSERT INTO avaliacao (nome, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5)
VALUES ('maria', '{$perguntas['id']}', '6', '7', '8', '9')";

return mysqli_query($conexao, $query2);
?>
```

Tenho esse banco de questões:
[image: tabela questoes]

Gostaria de pegar essas questões aleatórias e inseri-las nos q1,q2, etc
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Basicamente um quiz ou vestibular diferente para cada candidato.

---

Executando a query:

```
SELECT * FROM questoes ORDER BY RAND() limit 5;
```

ele retorna 5 id das questões.. Ex.: 8 26 24 30 4

Não estou conseguindo (não sei, né) pegar esses 5 ids e fazer o insert into no registro desse novo candidato.

Comment: Seja Bem Vinda, descreva na pergunta qual o problema que você está tendo.

Comment: Qual o erro? O que está ocorrendo?

Comment: Aline, é importante que vc descreve qual a sua dificuldade, não somente o que você quer fazer.

Comment: Não consigo fazer o INPUT dessas 5 questões no registro desse candidato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que entendi o problema está na hora de cadastrar as perguntas pra o candidato, já que o select está correto, você poderia fazer:

Primeiro percorrer os dados vindo do banco e coloca-los num array:

```
$q = [];
while ($perguntas = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    array_push($q, $perguntas);
}
```

Depois coloca-los na tabela de avaliação:

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO `avaliacao` (`nome`, `q1`, `q2`, `q3`, `q4`, `q5`)
VALUES ('maria', '{$q[0]['id']}', '{$q[1]['id']}', '{$q[2]['id']}', '{$q[3]['id']}', '{$q[4]['id']}')";
```

Assim você pega os 5 resultados vindo do banco, os quais irão vir aleatórios e os coloca na tabela de avaliação.

Comment: Está registrando tudo como 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

Comment: Corrigi a resposta, teste agora

Comment: UAU!!!  Estou uns 2 dias quebrando a cabeça com isso... Obrigadaaaaaa

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro, se precisa da chave primária da questão, não precisa selecionar todas as colunas do banco, selecione apenas a que vai utilizar. Também não é necessário fazer um laço de repetição para percorrer todas as questões selecionadas, você pode obter um *array* direto com a função `mysqli_fetch_all`:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT id FROM questao ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5");
$questoes = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$ids = array_column($questoes, 'id');
```

Assim, `$ids` será um *array* do tipo `[8, 2, 5, 7, 3]`.

Para passar estes valores inserindo na outra tabela, pode fazer:

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexao, "INSERT INTO avaliacao (nome, q0, q1, q2, q3, q4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'siiiii', $nome, ...$ids);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Assim, todos os ids da sua *array* passarão para a SQL, bem como o nome do aluno que fará a prova.

Documentações:

- [mysqli_fetch_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php);
- [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php);
- [mysqli_prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php);
- [mysqli_stmt_bind_param](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php);
- [mysqli_stmt_execute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php);